# Deserialisation JSON in SWIFT 2.2 from WCF

Tags: ios, json, swift, deserialization

I'm having troubles parsing JSON in swift
Here Is my code:

```
func HTTPsendPostRequestJSon(callString: String, callBody: NSData, callback:(JSonResult) -> Void){

    let result: JSonResult = JSonResult()
    let urlString = LMVariables.baseURL + callString
    let WCFUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: WCFUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = callBody
    request.addValue("application/JSON", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/JSON", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            result.err = error
            callback(result)
        } else {

            if let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                result.JSon = jsonData
            }
            callback(result)                    
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

This is the JSON I'm receiving from the server(when converting the NSData to string):

```
{
    "AccountTypeID": null,
    "BirthDate": null,
    "ErrorID": 268435456,
    "GSM": "",
    "GenderID": null,
    "IsActive": null,
    "IsConfirmed": null,
    "LaiksActive": null,
    "LangID": null,
    "LastActiveEventID": null,
    "LastActiveEventIsFinished": null,
    "LogonToken": null,
    "NewAccount": false,
    "PNToken": "",
    "PW": "",
    "ResourceUri": null,
    "USREmail": "",
    "USRFirstName": "",
    "USRLastName": ""
}
```

But the problem resides in the `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` call.
This is how the dictionary looks like after deserialisation:
(a lot of the fields are empty here, but I have the same result when my fields contain data)

```
jsonData    NSDictionary    19 key/value pairs  0x00007fcf14809080
[0] (null)  "LastActiveEventID" : (no summary)
[1] (null)  (no summary) : Int64(268435456)
[2] (null)  "NewAccount" : "0"
[3] (null)  "ResourceUri" : (no summary)
[4] (null)  "LastActiveEventIsFinished" : (no summary)
[5] (null)  "LogonToken" : (no summary)
[6] (null)  (no summary) : ""
[7] (null)  (no summary) : (no summary)
[8] (null)  (no summary) : (no summary)
[9] (null)  (no summary) : ""
[10]    (null)  (no summary) : ""
[11]    (null)  "USRFirstName" : ""
[12]    (null)  (no summary) : ""
[13]    (null)  (no summary) : (no summary)
[14]    (null)  (no summary) : (no summary)
[15]    (null)  (no summary) : (no summary)
[16]    (null)  "USRLastName" : ""
[17]    (null)  "AccountTypeID" : (no summary)
[18]    (null)  "LaiksActive" : (no summary)
```

As you can see, many keys are missing and replaced by (no summary).

The strange thing is that this same code worked before in swift 2.0.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Best,
Eric

Comment: Are you saying that some (or all) of the values are mysteriously getting set to `nil` but the keys are unaffected?

Comment: I'm confused by the console output.  What's up with the `<br>` tags, etc?  Can you try just showing us the output of `debugPrint(jsonData)` after the line `result.JSon = jsonData`?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @Jon: I've added there <br> on each line because while creating the question, the CRLF were not taken into account and everything was on one line. in the preview pane, so I added the HTML <br> tag. In the preview these pages where not visible and everything was showing correctly. I didn't know that once the question is published, these tags are shows and the CRLF are taken into account. I've removed them now.

Comment: I've print(jsonData) and strangely the output is fine:
{
    AccountTypeID = "<null>";
    BirthDate = "<null>";
    ErrorID = 268435456;
    GSM = "";
    GenderID = "<null>";
    IsActive = "<null>";
    IsConfirmed = "<null>";
    LaiksActive = "<null>";
    LangID = "<null>";
    LastActiveEventID = "<null>";
    LastActiveEventIsFinished = "<null>";
    LogonToken = "<null>";
    NewAccount = 0;
    PNToken = "";
    PW = "";
    ResourceUri = "<null>";
    USREmail = "";
    USRFirstName = "";
    USRLastName = "";
}
When I  print(jsonData.valueForKey("ErrorID")), I get the correct value

Comment: So, in the debug area the dictionary (shown in my original post) is not shown correctly, but when sending a print command to the output all the keys and values are correct. The problem is that I'm using ObjectMapper to map the dictionary to a class, but when I map the JSon dictionary my object is nil:

Comment: `code`             let result: JSonResult = res
            if result.err != nil {
                accResult.error = result.err
                self.protocolController?.didAccountSaved(accResult)
            } else {
                if let acc = Mapper<LMAccount>().map(result.JSon){
                    accResult.account = acc
                }
                self.protocolController?.didAccountSaved(accResult)
            } `code`

Comment: @paulvs: yes, as explained in my original post, the call returns a JSON object where all fields are empty except the errorID field  with an error code.

Comment: Based on that, I think the code in the question is working as intended, and your problem is in marshaling code elsewhere.  Note that `(no summary)` probably just means that the given object doesn't implement `Printable` or `DebugPrintable` protocols.

Comment: @jon, thanks for the info. Yes the problem must be elsewhere. I've been mislead by the debug wind,not seeing the keys. Thanks again for your support